# How to create localhost database using mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, windows, mysql-workbench

I download mysql installer here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

And then I downloaded MySql WorkBench.

At workbench's connection configuration I put hostname as "127.0.0.1", port "3306", user: "root", password is empty. I click "test connection" and it gives me this error:

"Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)"

What am I missing?

Comment: I updated the download link.

Comment: Press windows+R--> type 'services.msc'-->find mysql-->click on it--> click on 'start' appears on left

Comment: I noticed that this service is not installed!

Comment: You've probably installed mysql but didn't start the service.  The command to start the service is `mysqld`. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows. I've already searched the service twice. I will search again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html) for starting the service and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html) for how to make it permanent.
In short to test it, open a "DOS" terminal with administrator privileges and write:

```
shell> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\[YOUR MYSQL VERSION PATH]\bin\mysqld"
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using the [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) as it installs and updates the various MySQL products on your system, including MySQL Server, MySQL Workbench, and MySQL Notifier. The Notifier monitors your MySQL instances so you'll know if MySQL is running, and it can also be used to start/stop MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

removing temp files, and did you restart the computer or stop the MySQL service? That's the error message you get when there isn't a MySQL server running.

Comment: yeah! I noticed that I don't have any service related to MYSQL. Shouldnt the installer install it?

Comment: Not sure about that, might be fixed if you re-install the software.

Comment: The installer will install the service if while installation you have checked the check box named as mysql install as service

Comment: I will check that option, but I installed using the Full option.

Comment: this box doensn't exists.