# Start MySQL from the Windows Command Line

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to add IP address to user for allowing him remote control, from what I learn so far I need to paste this line in to the commend line.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'ip address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but when I did it , I received this error

[image]
* in the original attempt, 'user' , 'ip', 'password' be written, not like in this example.

why commend line beginning with `mysqluc>` and not with `mysql>` ?

I tried to use [How to create localhost database using mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544312/how-to-create-localhost-database-using-mysql) explanation but, it doesn't help.

Added :  I added environment variable, and when I write mysql, I[image] recived the following error  "

Comment: Because for some reason you started the utilities client (mysqluc) instead of the command line tool mysql. Simply start the proper tool and you'll be on your way.

Comment: thinks, where can I  found him?  in sql workbench ?

Comment: No, it's in the bin directory of mysql

Comment: thanks, what the name of the file  ? , mysqld I tried to open it but it not working

Comment: mysql.exe. msqld.exe is the daemon, aka the server process.

Comment: Did you actually install MySQL on that computer, or did you just unpack some zip file or whatever onto the disk? Normally, when properly installed, there's a mysql shortcut for user root (whose password you have entered during installation) available in the start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed `MySQL` then most probably the installation `bin` folder have already been added to `%PATH%` environment variable. Then in your command prompt type `mysql` and then issue the respective `GRANT` command.

Start `MySQL` client from command prompt like below. See [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) for more information.

```
mysql -u ODBC -p
```

Comment: Add more details in my Q

Comment: thank you , it  works properly , odbc is the user account :)